# how to use bash to run a same command with a group of variables?

Tags: bash

I want to run all those commands within some better arrangement, what should I do?

```
# bash script of "copyall.sh"
scp /local/michael.txt root@example.com:~/
scp /local/jason.txt root@example.com:~/
scp /local/jerry.txt root@example.com:~/
scp /local/wong.txt root@example.com:~/
scp /local/lee.txt root@example.com:~/
scp /local/mark.txt root@example.com:~/
```

For example it'd be very easy to do via JavaScript. I just need to put the names in an array  or object and for in that array/object. But what about with bash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need any variables here.

```
scp /local/michael.txt /local/jason.txt /local/jerry.txt \
    /local/wong.txt /local/lee.txt /local/mark.txt       \
    root@example.com:~/
```

You can also use the brace expansion:

```
scp /local/{michael,jason,jerry,wong,lee,mark}.txt root@example.com:~/
```

Comment: Oh, this works for the situation in the question but when the destination folders are in different places, it's not working, right? I get this conclusion via the first answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28316135/how-to-use-one-scp-command-to-copy-specified-files-from-local-to-server-for-tot

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo: Can you use `sftp` instead? I use it to copy many files from and to different locations.

Comment: Does sftp require the remote host to be running an ftp server?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `for` construct in `bash` too:

```
for name in michael jason jerry wong lee mark; do
    scp "/local/${name}.txt" root@example.com:~/
done
```

This runs the `scp` line once per name, replacing `${name}` with the current name.

`bash` supports explicit arrays as well, so you could do:

```
names=( michael jason jerry wong lee mark )
for name in "${names[@]}"; do
    scp "/local/${name}.txt" root@example.com:~/
done
```

As pointed out in @choroba's answer `scp` supports multiple parameters so you can do this more efficiently in a single command.

Comment: Please get in the habit of quoting all your `"$variables"`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells